# Invoke EL method with null-string parameter receives empty-string

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jboss

I have a PrimeFaces commandLink and I want to invoke an actionListener with some parameters. One of those parameters could be *null*. First I stumbled around [this issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-3177) and applied the patch 2152 found in the ticket to jbossweb 7.0.17 (this is the one shipped with JBoss).
The NPE is gone, but my actionListener gets an empty string passend as a parameter instead of *null*. I've also set the system property *org.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO* to *false*, but nothing has changed for the method invocation.

```
actionListener="#{fileDownloadBean.downloadChainFile(cc.attrs.forChain, cc.parent.attrs.value, cc.parent.attrs.header)}" 
// => cc.parent.attrs.header could be null but is passed as empty string
```

If I check for *null* value in JSF/xHTML via EL, everything is correct

```
#{cc.parent.attrs.header eq null}
// => returns true

//Edit 03.04.2015 18:05: returns also true
#{empty cc.parent.attrs.header}
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong? Is passing *null* to EL methods forbidden?

I'm using PrimeFaces 5.2, JBoss 7.1.3, Mojarra 2.1.29-jbossorg-1.

**Edit 11.04.2015 17:10**

As mentioned in a comment, I've already tested the context-param below, without success. It seems to only affect submitted values of UIInput-components.

```
javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL=true
```

Comment: Try the `empty` operator instead, as in `#{empty cc.parent.attrs.header}`

Comment: I don't know how this should help here - sorry. I need either the string value or *null*. Using *empty* will produce a boolean. Or do you mean the second code example? This returns also *true* - as expected.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking only at your second snippet

Comment: @grubi: Any solution?

Comment: @Toru: It is quite some time ago, I can't remember if I changed something. But the source code in the application is still the same. I think that we upgraded some library version, but I'm not sure. Our infrastructure changed a bit (e.g. jboss -> wildfly) and I can't have a look if a version changed.

Answer (score 0):

In your web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

[BalusC talks about this briefly here:](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the information that I have already added this param to may web.xml. Additionally it seems, that this param is only used inside of components extending UIInput. I can confirm, that I get _null_ from my inputText/inputTextarea/etc instead of an empty string, but I still get an empty string in the method invocation of the actionListener. Thank you anyway for reminding me to add this information.